# cx_Oracle error ORA-24315 when connecting ... sometimes

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I wrote a script and ran it on desktop 'A' which targeted an Oracle db (10g) and an app server on desktop 'B'. It ran without any problems.

I then copied the script over to desktop 'B' and it spat out the following: 'ORA-24315: illegal attribute type' at the following snippet:

```
cx_dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(cx_hostname, cx_port, cx_SID)
cx_connection = cx_Oracle.Connection(cx_username + '/' + cx_password + '@'+ cx_dsn )
```

Both machines were configured as follows:

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- 32-bit version of Python (ActiveState)
- pypm install cx-oracle (Which resulted in version cx_Oracle.clientversion() = (11, 2, 0, 3, 0) - Yes this does indicate v11 but it worked against the 10g version from Desktop 'A')

Desktop 'B' however had Oracle 10g and WebSphere 7 installed - Desktop 'A' did not

I have searched and lots of people have encountered this problem or something similar but in general the only suggested solutions were:

1. Ensure that the path doesn't reference Oracle libraries before the Python libraries - I guess the suggestion here is that the Oracle install on desktop B is inteferring. So I configured the path so that it only referenced Python (no mention of Oracle etc) - that didn't help
2. Make sure you are using 32 bit version of everything or 64 bit version of everything - I did, 32 bit across the board as far as Python was concerned
3. Ensure that the cx-Oracle matches the db you are targeting ... ok it looks like I have a problem but ... The strange thing is that the script does work on desktop 'A' so I imagine it must be something environmental on desktop 'B'. So off I go and install a dedicated 10g version of cx_Oracle. No success either.  (This query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456598/cx-oracle-multiple-instances-of-oracle-10-and-11-plus-oracle-home wasn't answered but sounds similar in nature)

So I am stuck - any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure all your variables and literals are byte strings and not unicode strings. It may be that.

Comment: I tried that and verified that it most definitely not a unicode string issue. I repeated the install on a clean XP machine and it worked without a problem connecting to Desktop 'B' so cx_Oracle must be picking up something from the Oracle db install locally on Desktop 'B' - when I get a resolution I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the ORA-24315 error after installing a second Oracle client in a different version. In the PATH environment variable we simply changed the order of the Oracle paths entries.Probably cx_Oracle considers only the first appearance of Oracle in the PATH variable.

Our configuration:
Win 7, Oracle 11.2.0.3, cx_Oracle-5.1.1-11g.win32-py2.6

Change:
Additionally installed Oracle 10.2.0

Resulting Error message:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-24315: illegal attribute type

How we got it to work again:
changed PATHs order from 
path_to_Oracle10;path_to_Oracle11;...
to 
path_to_Oracle11;path_to_Oracle10;...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error *ORA-24315* no matter how I tried to connect.

Solution:

I originally downloaded/installed the Ora11g version, but the database is 10g. 
I installed the 10g version of cx_Oracle, and the connection worked the first time.